# Change the text color of all the cells in a table view

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ipad

Is there a way to change the color of the text in ALL of the cells in a table view? I've looked this up before and it only talks about ways to change the text color of one cell. And my app does not have a set number of cells, so this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Do:

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: Xcode just gives me an error that there is a stray ` in the program, which you put there on purpose?

Comment: No remove those. I use both code brackets and backticks bij accident to highlight the code in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `textLabel` property of the UITableViewCell. But you cannot change the frame size of the textLabel.

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

To change the frame size and stuff, you will need to create a `UILabel` and give it a proper frame, color and text and then add it as a SubView.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview: myLabel];
```

For this approach, make sure to take care of the reusability problems (you will need to subclass`UITableViewCells` and create `CustomUITableViewCells`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one of two ways:

1. Implement a custom UITableViewCell subclass that sets the label's textColor to your desired color.
2. Change textColor inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. Just insert the following code somewhere before return cell;

   ```
   cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the delegate method, and change dynamically the visible rows...

Try this out:

```
NSEnumerator *e = [[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectEnumerator];
id object;
while (object = [e nextObject]) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:object];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Works like a charm.